# "Je vais te me les disperser" ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, oral

I wanted to provide a picture in case I was misreading this or something. I can't fathom how this sentence is grammatically viable. Three object pronouns in a row?

[image]

Comment: Look up "ethical dative". It's a way to render the sentence more personal by adding 1st and/or 2nd person dative pronouns to a verb phrase. Generally, it's just one, but it can break the usual template by adding more pronouns than normally allowed to a verb, as you have here.

Comment: Is "le ciel t'est tombé sur la tête" an example"? Because that is familiar to me and makes sense. But "me te les"? Especially when he's only dispersing the characters referred to by *les*.

Comment: *Le ciel t'est tombé sur la tête* is standard French.

Comment: Geez, totally the first time I've encountered this phenomenon, in 9 years.

Comment: I'm not sure, but to me it's not correct, it's some kind of casual "mistake" you can make (intentionally ?) when you're angry. I've only seen this in (old) BDs. Maybe it fell out of use ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat: It's not a bug, it's a feature.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as most French grammar books are concerned, this form of double [ethical dative](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/datif_%C3%A9thique) doesn't exist.

However, the reality is that it is definitely understood by native French and still used in colloquial spoken French. It can also be found in forums/blogs where the syntax is "relaxed".

Here is the first paragraph of an article about it - [Je vais te me lui régler son compte : les limites de la syntaxe](https://pratiques.revues.org/2687) by Alain Deschamps - which clearly describes this structure:

> Bien que des structures comme
>
> *Je vais te me lui ou je vais te me le + Verbe*
>     *Je te me lui ou je te me le + Verbe*
>
> soient unanimement rejetées par les puristes et ne figurent pas dans les grammaires du français, elles sont pourtant produites, reconnues et comprises par les locuteurs francophones même par ceux qui les refusent comme non grammaticales. Des exemples comme
>
> (1) « ça me coupe toutes les sensations. » **je te me lui ai** passé un de ces savons ! (tiens d’ailleurs, il ne me parle plus maintenant que j’y pense... )
>
> (2) Profite de Paris, c’est quand même la plus belle ville du monde et c’est VRAI (le premier qui dit le contraire, **je te me le** bastonne en beauté !)
>
> qui appartiennent sans conteste exclusivement à la langue orale et se rencontrent à l’écrit, presque uniquement sur Internet, notamment dans des blogs, illustrent bien les processus créatifs du langage et dépassent les limites de la syntaxe traditionnelle.

Grevisse mentions this ethical dative:

> La langue familière emploie d'une manière explétive le pronom de la 1<sup>e</sup> ou de la 2<sup>e</sup> personne, pour exprimer l'intérêt que le locuteur prend à l'action ou pour solliciter l'interlocuteur de s'intéresser à l'action (c'est le *dativus ethicus* de la grammaire latine).
> [...]
> On a parfois deux pronoms explétifs : *Avez-vous vu comme je te vous lui ai craché à la figure ?* (V. Hugo) - *Ce bougre-là [...], je vais te me le coller au bloc* (R. Gary)

Answer (score 9):

It's also know as "dative of interest". It's mostly an emphatical marker common in French, but also used as a way to "call in" someone: *Regarde-moi ça!*, "Look at it!" has an additional "call-out" element to it.

(*le ciel t'est tombé sur la tête* is a separate construction that is used with [inalienable possessions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inalienable_possession) equivalent to and more common than *le ciel est tombé sur ta tête*, it's an example of what is often referred to as "external possession", marking the possession outside the noun phrase)