# What other verbs can be used in the exclamatory expression "Regardez-moi ça !"?

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques

> **Regarde(z)**-moi ça !

"Regarder" is one of the most commonly used verbs with this *idiosyncratic* construction, there being more to the function of "moi" than meets the eye.

I wonder what other verbs can be used? I don't suppose practically anything will do, will it? What do you think about:

> **Visez**-moi ça.
>
> **Mangez**-moi ça.

Incidentally, I'm not talking about examples like the following where the use of "moi" is required and makes perfect sense.

> **Expliquez**-moi ça.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the list would be quite long.

- *Sentez-moi ça*
- *Goûtez-moi ça*
- *Écoutez-moi ça*
- *Buvez-moi ça*
- *Rangez-moi ça*
- *Jetez-moi ça*
- *Changez-moi ça*
  ...

*Moi* is here an ethical dative, similar to the ones discussed in [that question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/27874/1109).

Comment: I wonder if there is a rule  that determines what verbs can be used and what verbs cannot.

Comment: Probably any verb that can be used to suggest or order someone to do something with something (*ça*). *Oubliez-moi ça !*

Comment: Indeed, it should necessarily be followed by a direct object (be it a pronoun, a noun or a phrase): **Pars-moi* or **Rentre-moi chez toi* are incorrect, but *Fiche-moi le camp* , *range-moi ce désordre* or *regarde-moi ce bel enfant !* are correct.

Comment: Another note: you can also use it with other verbal forms than the imperative, as long as there is an idea of a suggestion or order: *Tu vas me goûter ça*, *Il faut que tu me goûtes ça*, *si tu m'écoutais, tu me gôuterais ça*,*demain, tu me goûteras ça*, and even with other persons than moi/nous: *d'accord, je vais te goûter ça*

Comment: @Greg *Je vais te me lui faire goûter ça !* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

"moi" dans cette expression est là pour renforcer l'injonction. on pourrait dire "pour moi", ou "c'est moi qui te le demande". like starting the sentence with "I'm asking you (...)".