# Un verbe peut-il être doublement pronominal ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, verbes-pronominaux

Dans cette phrase, on comprend qu'il est question de s'arracher quelque chose, de populaire, par exemple :

> On se l'arrache.

Dans celle-ci, on comprend qu'il est question de m'arracher (quoi donc ? on ne sait pas, ici) :

> On m'arrache.

Si je souhaite dire que l'on s'arrache ma personne, peut-on dire :

> On se m'arrache

Quelle est la règle pour un verbe « doublement » pronominal comme ici ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La combinaison *se me* **n'est pas grammaticale en français**

En effet, à moins que l'un des deux pronom ne soit un pronom "explétif" (datif d'intérêt ou datif éthique, [discuté assez récemment ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27874)), les pronoms *me, se, te, nous* et *vous* en position **d'objet**, ne peuvent se combiner entre eux ou avec *lui* et *leur*. (Grevisse, *Bon Usage* 14e ed., §682 b)

Notons toutefois que la formule spécifique dont il est question ici (*on se m'arrache* et variantes) est une expression figée qui est apparemment en usage "de manière plaisante", selon Grevisse.