# Il se (vous) torche

Tags: grammaire

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois* II :

> vous le retrouvez terrible ennemi, il vous diffame, dénonce, dort plus
> qu'on vous escalope !... il vous boufferait ! n'importe quoi pour
> l'éponge ! que c'est la damnation de sa vie qu'il vous a jamais connu
> ! et il jure ! le crache en l'air ! et **il se vous torche** !
> publiquement !...

Quelle est la fonction de *vous* dans *il se **vous** torche* ?

Comment: Il s'agit d'un "datif éthique" un peu original. Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27874/je-vais-te-me-les-disperser

Comment: @jlliagre Merci !

Comment: En tant que Français, je ne comprends pas cette structure. J'utilise et comprends le datif éthique (je ne savais pas que cela avait un nom) tel que "je me regarderais bien un film ce soir", mais les formes encore plus alambiquées telles que celle citée ici, ou d'autres vues ici : https://journals.openedition.org/pratiques/2687 me paraissent incompréhensibles. A vrai dire je ne sais même pas si c'est "se" ou "vous" qui est le datif éthique ici, et donc je ne sais pas si le sens est "se torcher" ou "torcher quelqu'un".

Comment: @jlliagre Ce qui semble peu courant pour un datif éthique, c'est l'absence d'un pronom *le/la/les* ou *lui/leur* dans dans la phrase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Je vais te me les disperser" ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27874/je-vais-te-me-les-disperser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il s'agit d'un datif éthique un peu original, car les formes associées à ***nous*** ou ***vous*** sont très rares d'après le document [Je vais te me lui régler son compte : les limites de la syntaxe](https://pratiques.revues.org/2687).

Céline n'est pas avare de datifs éthiques. Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois*, on en trouve une dizaine :

> *Je vais **te lui** en foutre des questions !*

> *Je **te le** naturaliserai, t'entends, naturaliserai !*

> *je **te le** désenvoûterai, moi*

> *je vais **te le** faire se retourner, moi !*

> *Et **te leur** roulait de ces patins !*

> *le sublime Jules ! et il **nous le** diffame ! il ose !*

> *Doucettement cocotte ! Venez ici et vos flauberts ! qu'à vingt-cinq pas l'on **se vous** troue ! Vingt-cinq pas ? faudrait que je dispose ! Vingt-cinq pas
> où ? mon cageot ? quatre !*,

> *si ça va mal vous êtes à pendre, si ça va bien on vous étreint, on **se vous** délecte, on vous hume, on se panouit de votre moindre oui...*

et donc :

> *vous le retrouvez terrible ennemi, il vous diffame,
> dénonce, dort plus qu'on vous escalope !... il vous
> boufferait ! n'importe quoi pour l'éponge ! que
> c'est la damnation de sa vie qu'il vous a jamais
> connu ! et il jure ! le crache en l'air ! et il **se vous** torche ! publiquement !...*

L'ordre des pronoms retenu par Céline est celui qui est observé le plus couramment d'après l'étude citée (90 %), donc *il **se vous** torche* doit certainement être compris comme une évolution de *il **vous** torche* par ajout du datif éthique ***se***, de la même manière que les deux autres occurrences de ***se vous***.

Answer (score -1):

''Il vous torche''que vous soyez anéanti, à bout, complètement vaincu  ne lui suffit pas, non, pour son plaisir sadique il vous élimine en pensée encore en chair et en os  pour sa propre satisfaction d'individu pervers, donc il se paye votre corps, il se le paye, il se le paye tout en vous torchant > Il se vous paye votre corps, il se vous le paye, il se vous le torche.          Plus, il ne pourra faire de mal à vos corps et esprit.                         Formulation originale, certes, mais possible utilisée en cas d'extrême inimitié. Il ne vous aime vraiment pas, jamais. Fin.

Comment: En quoi ceci répond-il à la question ?