# Je te vous lui ai craché à la figure

Tags: pronoms, syntaxe

[Les Mis](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/17489/17489-h/17489-h.htm), Livre 7, Chapitre III, Fantine:

> Puis s'adressant aux soldats:
> —Dites donc, vous autres, avez-vous vu comme je te vous lui ai craché à la figure?

Il y a longtemps j'ai appris à interpréter des phrases comme « je vous lui ai craché à la figure » : *vous* êtes les bénéficiaires de cette action que je *lui* fais. Mais pourquoi est-ce qu'elle ajoute ce *te* ? Qu'est-ce qu'il apporte à la phrase ?

Comment: Fantine est illettrée et ne maîtrise pas l'usage des pronoms. D'où les fautes de Français comme quelques lignes plus loin : "nous autres nous sommes là pour qu’on s’amuse".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Je vais te me les disperser" ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27874/je-vais-te-me-les-disperser)

Comment: @Graffito What's the problem with that line?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Ah, good find. I see I even upvoted the accepted answer there, so I must have read and forgotten it. How do you interpret the addition of 'tu' semantically? Is she implicating both the soldats (vous) *and* Javert (te), for example?

Comment: Indeed, the problem with that line was only my understanding at first glance. As "on" is frequently (and wrongly) used instead of "nous", it's my mistake, because in this context "on" (the people, not us) is ok.

Comment: @Graffito *Wrongly?* C'est exagéré, non ? Même l'Académie n'est pas aussi sévère avec ce *on*.

Comment: Bizarre. "Je te vous lui ai craché à la figure" me semble improbable. "Je vais te me les disperser", pas de problème dans le genre "gouaille". Pour la première phrase, dans le même genre, je dirais: "avez-vous vu comme je te lui ai craché à la figure?"

Comment: @LukeSawczak Je seconde Graffito, l'usage des pronoms est éxagéré, et l'effet est double, de gouaille et d'illetrisme en même temps. La phrase est "cassée".

Comment: @LukeSawczak Cette phrase ressemble à celle de la Q référencée comme doublon mais verse encore plus dans la surenchère de langage incorrect, à mon avis. "Te vous" est redondant, tandis qu'on peut à la rigueur prêter à "te me" une certaine logique (invective de l'interlocuteur et motivation adressée à soi-même). Elle pourrait légitimement rester une Q indépendante de par sa spécificité.