# "Je me vais te chauffer ça"?

Tags: grammaire

Reading *Astérix*, came across a sentence that didn't really make any sense. I know *s'en aller*, but not *s'aller*. Could this be a typo? Surely not, but ChatGPT couldn't explain it either.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the *me* of the beneficiary, similar to [your previous question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27874/je-vais-te-me-les-disperser), but in a different order for some reason?

Comment: Oh dang is it that again? I see it so, so rarely that I didn't recognize it the second time around either. Especially since the pronoun is in a different place this time - "je vais te me" last time, "je me vais te" this time. At least it doesn't resemble anything else, it's so weird.

Comment: I would still love to see an answer with a good explanation of why the order is different, if it's the same one! I've been perplexed by variations in this phenomenon too, e.g. https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52791/je-te-vous-lui-ai-crach%c3%a9-%c3%a0-la-figure?noredirect=1#comment110533_52791

Comment: @LukeSawczak It's just familiar/slang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like with the [previous question on a similar subject](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27874/je-vais-te-me-les-disperser), it's a case of [ethical dative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ethical_dative). The ***me*** is there, as Grevisse says, *to express the interest of the locutor in the action*. The pronoun location, more regular than in *je vais te me les disperser* doesn't affect its role and makes the sentence less surprising to the ear. It can be compared to ***Je m'en vais** te chauffer ça*.

Following is a gem found in an *Achille Talon* comic strip (Greg, *Fou et usage de fou, Pilote #425*, 1967), containing a ***triple*** ethical dative ! It is even reinforced by the final ***moi***.

---

Comme dans la [question précédente sur le même sujet](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27874/je-vais-te-me-les-disperser), il s'agit bien d'un [datif éthique](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/datif_%C3%A9thique). Le ***me*** sert à, comme le dit le Grevisse, *exprimer l'intérêt que le locuteur prend à l'action*. L'emplacement du pronom, plus régulier que dans dans *je vais te me les disperser* n'affecte pas son rôle et rend la phrase moins surprenante à l'oreille. On peut la rapprocher de ***Je m'en vais** te chauffer ça*.

Voici une perle extraite d'un épisode d'*Achille Talon* (Greg, *Fou et usage de fou*, *Pilote n°425*, 1967), où l'on trouve un **triple** datif éthique ! Il est même renforcé par un ***moi*** final.

---

[image]

Comment: How do you even tell which one is the "real" one in "te lui vous faire"? is it always the last one?

Comment: The context tells the "root" sentence is ***Je vais lui faire un petit dessin***, then *je **me** vais* insists on the interest of the subject (like the final ***moi***), the ***te*** includes the character in front of the speaker in the action and finally the ***vous*** widens this inclusion to everyone around him.

Comment: Note that a **triple** ethical dative is pretty extreme. I never heard any in my whole life. The one I found is likely an hapax.

Comment: Wow, learned a new word in English out of this too. Thanks for the bonus, @jlliagre! By the way, is it a coincidence that every case of this we've seen in both my questions as well as your additional citation involver *aller*? Does it only (or most often) occur in French with *aller*?

Comment: Most examples use *aller* indeed. There is one on [this page](https://journals.openedition.org/pratiques/2687) that doesn't: *le premier qui dit le contraire, **je te me le bastonne** en beauté !*